# External reference to a file that gets replaced

Tags: excel, function, external, ref

I've got a file on my local drive that is being replaced with a newer version of it every 10 minutes. 
I'd like to make a function reference to this file in another workbook, but the link is being broken every time the automatically generated file is being replaced (which is perfectly logical). 
Is there a way to retain a link to the external file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps keep an identical name for the file that keeps being replaced.

i.e instead of "Timesheet 10/08/2016 10:07" give it a custom name which remains immutable; that way the link will remain unbroken as it will be referencing the same file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortutnately the file already has a static name (HPI.xlsx) and the link is getting broken anyway.